# A word or expression less cutting than "obviously" for "in a self explanatory manner"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adverbs, phrase-requests

In a sentence of this kind, in a programming environment:

> This construct is *"in a self explanatory manner"* not interpretable, since it raises an ambiguity over the language´s syntax which is not determinable by the language itself.

*"Obviously"* would fit the case of a clear wrong syntax, but this one is not obvious (to *(self)* explain), although self explanatory (explained stating the *(self)* obvious).

Especially, I **do want to judge the explanation as obvious, without judging the mistake as obvious**.

As an analogy for the english language, how should I say:

> The syntax "You I call" is *"obviously"* wrong since undetermined, however, the same syntax "Answers I need" is clearly interpretable, although *"in a self explanatory manner"* a wrong syntax, since the language by itself can not determine that Answers don´t need you.

Comment: Why is *you I call* wrong, let alone *obviously* wrong?

Comment: @JasonBassford I am afraid I am not fluent enough to really get this one, although I am glad you appreciated mine. (I had to think about it!)

Comment: What I meant is I don't understand why the example given is wrong at all . . . However, I do have an alternative word I can provide despite that.

Comment: @JasonBassford The second sentence is just an intent to show the logic I want to express in a wider context, please let me know if it is misleading. My concern is the first sentence.

Comment: X may not be taken for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word that can be used in place of *obviously*, and without a sense of "judgment," is [**demonstrably**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demonstrably):

> capable of being demonstrated
> able to be proven or shown : possible to demonstrate
> APPARENT, EVIDENT
>
> There is no *demonstrable* evidence that the treatment is effective.

Or:

> The syntax "You I call" is "*demonstrably*" wrong . . .

Comment: Without a sense of "judgment" is exactly why I don´t want "obviously" or "evident" (less cutting). Think about a simple (obvious) trapdoor, where seeing it is not obvious. I wouldn´t judge you for falling in the trap, but I can judge the trap as an obvious mechanism. *Demonstrably* would IMHO supose some kind of theorical reasoning to demonstrate that trapdoors open when you step on it, so you fall. In fact I **do want to judge the explanation as obvious, without judging the mistake as obvious**. Anyway I learned a new word today and I thank you for that.

Comment: @lucchi If I hold up my hand, and I'm missing a finger, I *demonstrably* have only four fingers ... (I've demonstrated it by showing it to you.)

Comment: After reading comments, I must admit that, as long as I will actually give the explanation, I can let the reader judge the explanation for himself. The syntax is *demonstrably* undetermined: X, thus invalid. Thank you so much.